# Create a new column and values with ifelse function

Tags: r

I am working with the `ggplot2` movies dataset and I need to create a new column "advice" that is the result of ratings. So for example, one of the values to be assigned is "skip" if the rating is below or equal to 5, "consider" if the rating falls between 5.1 and 8, etc.

I cannot make my code work. Can anybody enlighten me?

```
mov1$advice<-ifelse(mov1$rating<=5 & 
    mov1$rating(seq(from=5.1, to=8)) & mov1$rating >=8.1,
    "skip", 
    "consider",
    "must_see")
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output based on that

Comment: `mov1$rating(seq(from=5.1, to=8))` does not seem to be a logical value.  You also have three alternatives listed, whereas `ifelse` only takes two options `ifelse(condition,iftrue,iffalse)`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by slightly adjusting your code (adding a sublevel of `ifelse`):

```
mov1$advice <- ifelse(mov1$rating <= 5, 
                      "skip",
                      ifelse(mov1$rating >= 5.1 & mov1$rating <= 8,
                             "consider",
                             "must_see"))
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple and fast solution using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

setDT(mov1)

mov1[, advice := ifelse( rating <= 5, "skip",
                 ifelse( rating >= 5.1 & rating <= 8, "consider", "must_see"))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `cut` which is going to be cleaner than `ifelse` as the number of categories goes up in tasks like this.

```
library(ggplot2movies)
mov1 <- movies

mov1$advice <- cut(mov1$rating, breaks = c(0, 5, 8.1, Inf),
                   labels = c("skip", "consider", "must_see"),
                   right = FALSE)
summary(mov1$advice)

    skip consider must_see 
   14235    40481     4072
```